# 2-nd conditional with 'to be + past tense"

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Recently I have stumbled upon a 2-nd conditional structure differing from the commonly used one.

A sample sentence using such unusual (at least to me) grammar:

> The results would be incorrect, if the values **were to be** interpreted as integers.

The semantics of the conditional used by the author was "if the writer meant the values as integers", i.e. the author combined the 2-nd conditional grammar with the *to be to be* structure. That is, they attempted to shorten the sentence:

> The results would be incorrect, if the documentation stated "the values are to be interpreted as integers".

Is such a grammar correct? And if so, what are the rules when it should be used?

Comment: If the values are to be interpreted. signals a future thing, not yet done but that will be. If the values were (to be) interpreted is not something that is done. It's a supposition.

Comment: Are you asking if "*were to be interpreted*" is correct grammar, and what the rules are?

Answer (score 1):

Your example sentence has the same (perfectly valid) structure as

> I would buy a seaside villa if I were to be handed a fortune.

Its subordinate clause uses the passive voice. The sentence means exactly the same thing as

> If someone were to hand me a fortune, I would buy a seaside villa

which, of course, uses the verb *hand* in the active voice.

It is implicit in such sentences that their *were* clauses are counter factual. Here the speaker has not been handed a fortune and, *a fortiori*, hasn’t bought such a villa.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is correct if a bit unusual. The writer could have said

> If the values are interpreted [taken / read] as integers, then the results
> are incorrect.

There are no "rules", it's a matter of the writer's preferred style. The only rule you might apply is the general one "keep it simple" particularly when writing formal documents such as reports, manuals, papers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the grammar is good (just not the comma).

The structure for a "second conditional" is *[ "would" + base form + "if" + simple past ]*, and there are no restrictions on what sequence of tenses come after the *simple past* part.

In your case, the sequence of verbs in the "if"-clause begins with "were", and the sequence "*were to be interpreted*" is good grammar, so the whole structure is correct.